# Display flex not working as expected

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have used display: flex on my top-navigation on my site. The problem is that the link labelled as "Home" in my code below, show a little above than other links which follow the "Home" link. What I want is that the home link should show on the same line on which the other links are shown but I am unable to do it.

I have posted my HTML and CSS as well in `<style>` tag.
Hopefully someone know how to do it? Thanks..

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.Navigation2{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; 
    /*position: relative;*/
    font-family: "Segoe UI",Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    background-color: #4caf50;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 14px 0px;
}
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #4caf50;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.Navigation2 a{color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; padding: 14px 16px;}
.Navigation2 a#MyFacebook{display: block;}
.Navigation2 p#find {background-color: transparent; float: right; color: white; padding: 14px 16px; display: block; margin: 0px; /*position: relative; bottom: 12px;*/}
.Navigation2 p#find input{padding: 3px; border: 1px solid blue; /*position: relative; bottom: 2px;*/ border-radius: 7px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="Navigation2">
    <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="Home" href="NewFile.html">TUTORIALS</a>   
    <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a>HTML</a><br>
    <a>CSS</a><br>
    <a>Javascript</a><br>
    <a>JQuery</a><br>
    <a>Bootstrap</a><br>
    </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#">REFERENCES</a>
    <a href="#">EXAMPLES</a>
    <p id="find">Find: <input type="search" autofocus></p>
    <a href = "https://www.facebook.com/" id="MyFacebook"> MY FACEBOOK PAGE </a>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Try `vertical-align: middle;`

Comment: For which tag or class I should use (vertical-align: middle;) ???

Answer (score 0):

In your `Navigation2` class, add

```
align-items: 'center'
```

This will align the children's vertical alignment in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, make dropdown class as display : flex

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/bvyNrB

```css
.Navigation2{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; 
    /*position: relative;*/
    font-family: "Segoe UI",Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    background-color: #4caf50;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 14px 0px;
}
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #4caf50;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.Navigation2 a{color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; padding: 14px 16px;}
.Navigation2 a#MyFacebook{display: block;}
.Navigation2 p#find {background-color: transparent; float: right; color: white; padding: 14px 16px; display: block; margin: 0px; /*position: relative; bottom: 12px;*/}
.Navigation2 p#find input{padding: 3px; border: 1px solid blue; /*position: relative; bottom: 2px;*/ border-radius: 7px;}
```

```html
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="Navigation2">
    <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="Home" href="NewFile.html">TUTORIALS</a>   
    <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a>HTML</a><br>
    <a>CSS</a><br>
    <a>Javascript</a><br>
    <a>JQuery</a><br>
    <a>Bootstrap</a><br>
    </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#">REFERENCES</a>
    <a href="#">EXAMPLES</a>
    <p id="find">Find: <input type="search" autofocus></p>
    <a href = "https://www.facebook.com/" id="MyFacebook"> MY FACEBOOK PAGE </a>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Thanks @tayyab for the update , please mark my post as answer if it helped you to resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

```css
.Navigation2{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    /*position: relative;*/
    font-family: "Segoe UI",Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    background-color: #4caf50;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 14px 0px;
    align-items: center;
}
.dropdown {
    position: relative;

}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {

    background-color: #4caf50;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.Navigation2 a{color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; padding: 14px 16px;}
.Navigation2 a#MyFacebook{display: block;}
.Navigation2 p#find {background-color: transparent; float: right; color: white; padding: 14px 16px; display: block; margin: 0px; /*position: relative; bottom: 12px;*/}
.Navigation2 p#find input{padding: 3px; border: 1px solid blue; /*position: relative; bottom: 2px;*/ border-radius: 7px;}
```

```html
<div class="Navigation2">
    <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="Home" href="NewFile.html">TUTORIALS</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a>HTML</a><br>
    <a>CSS</a><br>
    <a>Javascript</a><br>
    <a>JQuery</a><br>
    <a>Bootstrap</a><br>
    </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#">REFERENCES</a>
    <a href="#">EXAMPLES</a>
    <p id="find">Find: <input type="search" autofocus></p>
    <a href = "https://www.facebook.com/" id="MyFacebook"> MY FACEBOOK PAGE </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What what the problem and what did you do to solve it?

Comment: I modify your navigation2 class by adding align-items: center; to it